# SQL group by aggregate varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out the SQL to aggregate the data in my `Vehicles` table:

```
Id | Name  | Make
---+-------+------
1    Car      Ford
1    Car      Volvo
1    Car      BMW
2    Bike     Honda
3    Truck    Tata
3    Truck    abc
4    Train    bullet
```

in order to return the following:

```
Id | Name  | Result
---+-------+------
1    Car      3 items selected
2    Bike     Honda
3    Truck    2 items selected
4    Train    bullet
```

So if an `Id,Name` combination has more than one make then output 'X items selected' where X is the number of makes for that combination. Otherwise output the Make as-is. Note that the make will be unique for each Id,Name combination.

Can this be achieved using a GROUP BY expression? If so what aggregate function do I need in place of ??? below? Or can it be achieved some other way?

```
select Id, 
    Name, 
    case when count(Make) > 1 then convert(varchar(10), count(Make)) + ' items selected'
    else ??? end Result
from Vehicles 
group by Id, Name
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: `else max(make)`? BTW, do `count(distinct make)`.

Comment: @jarlh oh I didn't realise max was applicable for a varchar column. That's perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MIN()` or `MAX()`:

```
select Id, Name, 
       (case when count(Make) > 1
             then convert(varchar(10), count(Make)) + ' items selected'
             else min(Make)
        end) as Result
from Vehicles 
group by Id, Name;
```

If there is only one row, then the `MIN()` and `MAX()` are the values on that row.

Answer (score 0):

Use CTE (Common Table Expression) because that increase your query performance.especially in your query. check the Query

```
      WITH Vehicles_CTE (Id, Name, Result,Make) 
      AS (  
          SELECT Id, Name, COUNT(1) Result, MAX(Make) Make   FROM   Vehicles
          Group By Id, Name 
         ) 
         SELECT Id, Name, CASE WHEN Result>1 
                            THEN Cast(Result AS varchar(10)) + ' items selected' 
                            ELSE Make End  Result FROM   Vehicles_CTE
```